# Custom :language cakephp

Tags: cakephp, multilingual, cakephp-2.3

We succesfully build a multiple language *(NLD/DEU/ENG)* cakephp website (cakephp 2.3.6). And now our client wants us to add the belgium language to his website. The [code list](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) doesn't contain a code for the Belgium language. it's either dut (Dutch; Flemish) or fre (French).

But instead of having this url: *example.com/dut/controller/action*
We would want to have this: *example.com/bel/controller/action*

Is it possible to work with *'dut'*, but show *'bel'* in the url? Or is there a way to add a 'custom' language?

Comment: There is no such thing as a belgian language, but belgian variants of mostly french and dutch, then german. I'm pretty sure though that if you define a variant that doesn't exist (like bel) cake won't complain if you provide the necessary translation files too. But if you decide bel=dutch, the other half of belgians will be offended :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the standard code for the language, the Belgian language does not exist (there are three official languages, Dutch, French, German). But if you have localized content for a particular country, then you should use the country code.

There are countries that have more than one official language (Belgium, Switzerland, Spain, Bosnia and Herzegovina, ..). In this case you should use a combination of language-country code as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(v=vs.85).aspx)

Your URL should look like:

**for the German country and language**

> www.example.com/de/

**for the Netherlands and the Dutch language**

> www.example.com/nl/

**for Belgium and the official language**

> www.example.com/nl-be/
>   www.example.com/fr-be/

In your AppController beforefilter put a switch statement, where you specify the rules for the language and localized content

**EDIT** (add example)

```
    AppControler.php
public function beforeFilter()
{
    switch ($this->params['lang'])){
        // for nederland
        case: 'nl':
            Configure::write('Config.language', 'dut');
            $this->set('for_country','nl');
            break;
        // for germany
        case: 'de':
            Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');
            $this->set('for_country','de');
            break;
        // for belgium / dutch speakers
        case: 'nl_be':
            Configure::write('Config.language', 'dut');
            $this->set('for_country','be');
            break;
        // for belgium / french speakers
        case: 'nl_fr':
            Configure::write('Config.language', 'fr');
            $this->set('for_country','be');
            break;
        // default english
        case: 'en':
            Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
            $this->set('for_country','us');
            break;
    }
}

PostsController.php

public function index ()
{
    // find all posts for country, example only content for Belgium in french
    // example.com/nl_fr/posts
    $options = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Post.localized' => $for_country
        )
    );
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all',$options);
    .......
}
```

Comment: Codes for speaking variants should be underscored instead of dashed, ie `nl_be` instead of `nl-be`.

Comment: @user221931 "_Codes for speaking variants should be underscored_" says who?

Comment: @ndm, it's defined by ICU someplace. I'm not sure if it's mandatory or just a recommendation but it's the way I've seen it everywhere. I'm from mobile so this is coming from memory if I'm mistaken please feel free to correct me.

Comment: @user221931 I'm not familiar with the ICU specs on this, but having a quick look it seems that they are more about on how to handle things API wise, and not about how codes should be expressed in URLs. Note that internally CakePHP maps the hypened variants to underscored variants, see [**`L10n::$_l10nCatalog`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.7/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php#L184)!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
We always thought that Cakephp used a 3 digit code for languages not 2. From previous experience Cakephp would not recognise our .po file if we didn’t use the 3 digit code stated in the code list. 
We have no idea how we can implement the 2 digit code. Can you show an example?

Comment: Oh wait, I get it now also thanks to ndm's link that gave me extra information =] Sorry for my blonde moment. Going to try if I can get it to work.